# Calling MethodInfo.Invoke Fails in Azure Function Startup

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, system.reflection, methodinfo

I have a .Net Core 3.1 application that is implemented as an Azure Function (v3) that fails on startup.  In the function app project, I implemented a `Startup` class that adds the various services to the `IServiceCollection` collection for dependency injection.  I have one assembly that I need to load manually using reflection, and call a method that will add all of the services defined in that assembly to the `IServiceCollection` collection.  As you can see below, it is the line `method.Invoke(null, new Object[] { services });` that fails.  There doesn't seem to be a problem loading the assembly, getting the type information, or the method information because none of the exceptions are thrown in this code.  You can see that I am calling a static method of a static class, hence the `null` parameter to the `Invoke` method.  I have tried using a non-static class and using the `Activator.CreateInstance` method to pass an object instance to the `Invoke` method, but get the same error.  This code can execute without error while running locally, and only seems to have a problem once published to the Azure Function resource.

Here are the contents of my Startup.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Some.Name.Space.FunctionApp.Startup))]
namespace Some.Name.Space.FunctionApp
{
    public sealed class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            IServiceCollection services = builder.Services;

            var assemblyNamespace = "Some.Name.Space";
            String? baseDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(GetType().Assembly.Location);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(baseDirectory))
            {
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(baseDirectory, $"{assemblyNamespace}.dll")));
                var typeName = $"{assemblyNamespace}.SomeClassName";
                Type? type = assembly.GetType(typeName);
                if (type != null)
                {
                    var methodName = "SomeMethodName";
                    MethodInfo? method = type.GetMethod(methodName);
                    if (method != null)
                    {
                        method.Invoke(null, new Object[] { services });  // THIS IS LINE THAT FAILS.
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new MissingMethodException($"Unable to find the {methodName} method in the {typeName} type.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new TypeLoadException($"Unable to load {typeName} from {assembly.GetName()}.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Unable to get the Location directory for the function application.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the problem is not accurately described by the error message below because the entire application runs fine if I simply comment out the one line that fails, and there is plenty of other code that has dependencies to the ''Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions' assembly.  Here is a screenshot of the error I see in Azure:
[image]

Comment: The library you load dynamically in that routine needs `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` namespace. So make sure you package this nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/ Put that library you are loading in the same directory as your Azure function dll if your project already imports that package.

Comment: The library I'm loading dynamically does use the ```Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection``` namespace.  The library has an indirect reference to the 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll' via a separate package that is uses (that separate package has a reference to the *.Abstractions.dll package).

Comment: Also, if I remove the reflection functionality, and set a project/assembly reference to the package and call the method directly (it's implemented as an extension method of the ```IServiceCollection``` interface), then everything works.  In my case, I need to NOT have a project/assembly reference to this library I'm trying to dynamically load.

Answer (score 0):

I can't honestly say why my solution works, but I suspect it has something to do with how the `Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)` method might be using the `System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext` class.  My suspect that my original implementation did not load the correct assembly, even though it was able to load an assembly with the name I was expecting.  The solution below has default `Version`, `Culture` and `PublicKeyToken`  values for display, so you would need to use the correct values for those properties in your implementation.

Here are the contents of the new Startup.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Some.Name.Space.FunctionApp.Startup))]
namespace Some.Name.Space.FunctionApp
{
    public sealed class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            IServiceCollection services = builder.Services;
            var assemblyNamespace = "Some.Name.Space";
            AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName($"{assemblyNamespace}, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
            var typeName = $"{assemblyNamespace}.SomeType";
            Type? type = assembly.GetType(typeName);
            if (type != null)
            {
                var methodName = "SomeMethod";
                MethodInfo? method = type.GetMethod(methodName);
                if (method != null)
                {
                    method.Invoke(null, new Object[] { services });
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new MissingMethodException($"Unable to find the {methodName} method in the {typeName} type.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new TypeLoadException($"Unable to load {typeName} from {assembly.GetName()}.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```